# Reading view using spring-data jpa - hiberanate AUTO JPA Generation type

Tags: java, hibernate, sql-server-2008, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I have a database view which I read in java using spring data JPA.

```
class XView{
    private Long id;
    //Other column and constructors

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    public Long getId()
    {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id)
    {
        this.id = id;
    }

}
```

So when I try to read it, it gives me below error:

```
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Invalid column name 'id'.
at net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.SQLDiagnostic.addDiagnostic(SQLDiagnostic.java:368)
at net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.TdsCore.tdsErrorToken(TdsCore.java:2820)
at net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.TdsCore.nextToken(TdsCore.java:2258)
at net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.TdsCore.getMoreResults(TdsCore.java:632)
at net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.JtdsStatement.executeSQLQuery(JtdsStatement.java:477)
at net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.JtdsPreparedStatement.executeQuery(JtdsPreparedStatement.java:778)
at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.extract(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:82)
... 56 common frames omitted
```

But the main purpose of generating it is because it is not present in the view.

Comment: The view does not seem to have a column with id and you did not define mapping for id using @Column. can you share how view looks like

Comment: ????????@GeneratedValue refers to generating the value.You have no column named id in the referenced view.